# Find supremum of the set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A=\left\{t~\sin(\frac{1}{t}): t\in (0,\frac{2}{\pi})\right\}$. Then what would be suprimum of $A$.

It looks like supremum will occur at $\frac{2}{\pi}$ and supremum value will be $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: Find the derivative of the function, set it to $0$, see where the second derivative is negative at the points where the derivative is $0$ on the desired interval. If none of the points are on the interval, check the boundary points (not defined at $0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supremum is indeed $\frac{2}{\pi}$. 
It cannot be more than $\frac{2}{\pi}$, because $|t| \leq \frac{2}{\pi}$ and $|\sin(\frac{1}{t})| \leq 1$.

Since $t \sin(\frac{1}{t})$ is continuous and $\frac{2}{\pi}\sin(\frac{1}{\frac{2}{\pi}}) = \frac{2}{\pi}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{2}{\pi}$, it holds that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \left( t \sin(\frac{1}{t})\right) = \frac{2}{\pi}$, and $\frac{2}{\pi}$ is the supremum.

Comment: similarly, infimum will be $\frac{-3}{2\pi}$. Am I correct?

Comment: $-\frac{2}{3\pi}$ , as $\sin (\frac{3\pi}{2}) = - 1$ (For $t = \frac{3}{2\pi}$ we get a positive $\sin$ value)